# Displaying Integer in a Label

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I display an integer in a Label? What I am doing is I am calculating the total and I am trying to display it in a label.

```
public partial class total : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int total;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["confirm"]["quantity"]);
        int quantity = (int)Session["TextBox1Value"];

        if (Request.Cookies["user"]["items"] == "Tyres")
        {
            total = 20 * quantity;

            Label2.Text = ???
        }
    }
}
```

Or is there any other way to display the total on same page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use**

```
Label2.Text = total.ToString();
```

**OR**

```
Label2.Text =  Convert.ToString(total);
```

Since `Text` takes a string so you have to convert your `total` integer value to string by calling `ToString()` or `Convert.ToString(int)`.

Comment: Use Debugger to see what value is there in total.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using .ToString() or Convert.ToString() methods.

```
Label2.Text = total.ToString();
```

or

```
Label2.Text =  Convert.ToString(total);
```